# Getting messages from kafka using storm

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-kafka

How to get the last offset time from zookeeper? when reading messages from kafka using storm spout. The context: Kafka gets messages continuously, consumer reads for a while and then shuts down due to any reason and then the consumer reads only the latest message but does not read from the last offset read

Answer (score 2):

> consumer reads for a while and then shuts down due to any reason

Not sure what exactly are you referring to as the consumer is supposed to run infinitely unless it is stopped explicitly.

Now assuming you are using the storm's [KafkaSpout](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka) implementation, there is a config called `forceStartOffsetTime` which is used `to force the spout to rewind to a previous offset`. The way to use it as follows

```
    spoutConfig.forceStartOffsetTime(-2);
```

As seen in the doc page

> It will choose the latest offset written around that timestamp to start consuming. You can force the spout to always start from the latest offset by passing in -1, and you can force it to start from the earliest offset by passing in -2.

so setting it to -2 will always force it to read from the start
what is the configuration you are using, would be great if you could post some code

Comment: but i dont need from the beginning or the latest message. does setting  -1 let me consume from the time where the consumer has not consumed or the latest that is current timestamp

Comment: It will choose the latest offset written around that timestamp to start consuming (*from doc*)

Comment: means -1 will force it to consume from the latest

Comment: so now i need to know the last timestamp where the consumer failed to receive the message.

Comment: could you please post some code .. that will help a lot to understand what exactly your issue is

Comment: Thanks. But there is no code for this particular thing. We came across a situation like this [HERE](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/12cherxwf5/fetch-messages-since-a-specific-time). So if I have to retrieve msgs, can I use zookeeper logs or anything else from which I will know the timestamp or offset to initialize reading the messages from there.